# Quebrar texto com expressão regular no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Estou tentando quebrar um texto utilizando expressão regular com JavaScript, mas não estou conseguindo obter o resultado esperado.

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
var texto = "texto inicial <div>Texto dentro da DIV</div> Texto fora da DIV <p>Texto dentro do P</p> texto final";
```

Preciso quebrar esse texto em um array para que fique da seguinte forma:

```
0: texto inicial
1: <div>Texto dentro da DIV</div>
2: Texto fora da DIV
3: <p>Texto dentro do P</p>
4: texto final
```

Este é o código que estou tentando:

```
var regex = new RegExp(".*[(<.*>.*<\/.*>)].*", "g");
var blocosTexto = texto.match(regex);

console.log(blocosTexto);
```

Comment: Não use *Regex* para analisar *HTML*. Por favor leia [Analisando Html a maneira Cthulhu](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/), se não souber ler inglês clique com o botão esquerdo do mouse sobre a página e traduza para o português(o mesmo é válido para os links sugerido por essa matéria).

Comment: Ao colocar algo entre colchetes, vc está definindo uma lista de caracteres, então `[(<.*>.*<\/.*>)]` significa "o caractere `(`, ou `<`, ou `.`, ou `*`, etc" (apenas um deles) - [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/O5nhLF/1/). De qualquer forma, regex não é a melhor forma, como já disseram. Pode até "funcionar" para casos simples, mas complique um pouco o HTML e [a regex começa a virar um "monstro"](/a/440262/112052).

Answer (score 5):

Dependendo da complexidade das tags HTML que estiverem contidas na sua string, fazer isso com *regex* pode deixar de ser trivial. É quase consenso, também, que expressões regulares [não devem ser usadas para fazer o *parse* de strings que contenham HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7445826).

Pode parecer absurdo, mas, se você está trabalhando com HTML, utilizar um *parser* de HTML pode não ser uma má ideia. Veja um exemplo que utiliza a API [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), presente nos navegadores:

```js
const htmlStr = 'texto inicial <div>Texto dentro da DIV</div> Texto fora da DIV <p>Texto dentro do P</p> texto final';

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlStr, 'text/html');

const arr = Array.from(doc.body.childNodes).map((node) => {
  const text = node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
    ? node.textContent
    : node.outerHTML;
    
  return text.trim();
});

console.log(arr);
```

Se você estiver em um ambiente que não suporte nativamente o DOMParser (como o Node.js), pode utilizar algum pacote que faz isso, como o [`jsdom`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom).

Utilizar um *parser* como esse será, na maioria dos casos (especialmente os mais complexos), melhor do que ficar lidando com expressões regulares (e que podem não ser totalmente adequadas à tarefa). A vantagem é que você tem uma API muito mais robusta para desenvolver à medida que a complexidade do HTML presente na string for crescendo.

Comment: Olá @Luiz Felipe, obrigado pela resposta rápida. Estou trabalhando em um editor de texto, e preciso ter controle do conteúdo do texto para fazer quebra de página corretamente e mostrar uma pré visualização para o usuário. Pode ser que exista outra forma de fazer esse controle, mas essa foi a que encontrei.

Comment: O `DOMParser` (e alternativas como o `jsdom`) são bons para resolver esse tipo de problema. No entanto, se _performance_ for uma preocupação, talvez eles não sejam ideais (embora _regex_ talvez também não — há de fazer os devidos testes para verificar). Nesse caso, pode ser uma outra opção também você desenvolver um pequeno e simples _parser_, visando exclusivamente aos seus requisitos.

Comment: Pode usar o próprio DOM do documento para fazer esse parsing. Por exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/u4c3phdt/

Comment: Realmente, @bfavaretto! :) Aliás, posso roubar a ideia do `nodeType` ao invés do `instanceof`? Este último me parece menos performático, e tinha esquecido-me do `nodeType`... :)

Comment: Pode sim, sem problemas